# How to inject variables into public-facing JS using wp_enqueue_script

Tags: php, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm using `wp_enqueue_script` to enqueue the public-facing JS of my WP plugin:

```php
wp_enqueue_script($this->PluginName, plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/public.js', array(), $this->version, false);
```

And in the other side I have:

```
var data = {
  name: ''
}
```

I would like, somehow, to set the name value to a value that I have access in the server side. Is this possible? Can someone point me to the documentation or an example of how to do that?

Comment: Take a look at `wp_localize_script()`  function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/